# useEffect re-rendering twice on every other click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to have a simple 4 button component that toggles the class of each so that only 1 is `active` at one time. I am using the following code on my buttons.

```
<NavLink
          to="/"
          className={On ? "nav-link-active" : "nav-link"}
          onClick={() => {
            setOn(true);
          }}
        >
```

And I am using state on all 4 buttons like so

```
const [On, setOn] = useState(false);
  const [On2, setOn2] = useState(false);
  const [On3, setOn3] = useState(false);
  const [On4, setOn4] = useState(false);
```

And finally I am using a simple if statement to ensure that only 1 of the buttons can stay active at one time.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useeffect");
    if (On === true) {
      setOn2(false);
      setOn3(false);
      setOn4(false);
    }
    if (On2 === true) {
      setOn(false);
      setOn3(false);
      setOn4(false);
    }
    if (On3 === true) {
      setOn2(false);
      setOn(false);
      setOn4(false);
    }
    if (On4 === true) {
      setOn(false);
      setOn3(false);
      setOn2(false);
    }
  }, [On, On2, On3, On4]);
// I know there's probably a better way to do this, it was just a quick fix.
```

This works for the most part, except the problem is that the `useEffect()` will run twice on every other click. Which then resets the buttons.

I have not worked with UseEffect() too much, so I am unsure why this is happening. How do I stop it from re-rendering twice? My full code is [viewable here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/Dylanbozarth.com/blob/active/src/components/navbar.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only a single state variable instead of multiple so you don't need any `useEffect`. You could have an index indicating the currently "on" button, 0 to 3, or -1 for none (following the usual JS numbering conventions):

```
const [buttonOn, setButtonOn] = useState(-1);
```

Then, for the JSX in the question, use instead:

```
<NavLink
          to="/"
          className={buttonOn === 0 ? "nav-link-active" : "nav-link"}
          onClick={() => {
            setButtonOn(0);
          }}
        >
```

And the next Nav would have `buttonOn === 1 ?` and `setButtonOn(1)`, etc.

Depending on the other navs and their contents, you might be able to make it less repetitive by using the index in a mapper function instead of writing out every nav.

Comment: Wow, I knew there was an easier way of doing it but I didn't think it would be so easy. This is working greatly for me, I will study your answer, thank you!